# How to make a Flask app environment accessible on an online Python REPL?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-services, flask, read-eval-print-loop

I wonder where to even start with doing something like this. We have a Flask app that runs on AWS and want to have a web REPL that can interact with that Flask app. Ideally we want to be able to run methods on the fly from this REPL that are defined in the Flask app, interact with DB models etc.

Where would one start?

Comment: "Where would one start?" By rethinking the idea. That sounds like a gaping security hole waiting to be exploited.

Comment: In theory, you write code, when you press enter you send that code to the backend, which runs the code and returns the result of running that code. Obviously just running any code someone sends you is not a good idea.

Comment: For one we're not expecting this to run over the wider web, just the internal portal. Second this is more of a hack project than something on production servers.